# jQuery: Create link on mouseover/hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML code. How can create a link on the entire div which when people click on it would take them to a specific link? basically an `"<a></a>"` tag on the entire DIV

```
<div class="unique">
  <div>
    <p>Lines of text</p>
      <p>Extra lines of text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

here is my jQuery script i have come up with, i just have no idea how to make the link in it

```
<script>
$( ".unique" ).mouseover(function() {
  $(this).LINK_TO_A_SPECIFIC_URL;
});
</script>
```

Comment: On mouseover? Users won't like this.

Comment: why does it only need to be a link on mouseover? what difference would it make if it was always a link?

Comment: I agree with @undefined... autoforwarding me on a mouseover and I will never come back to visit again.

Comment: i don't want to autoforward. It is a wordpress plugin i cannot modify and i tought of using jquery to create the link for that specific class

Comment: i want people to be able to click on it not to autoforward them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is not quite what you asked for. But, @undefined made a good point in his comment to your post.

So instead of just auto forwarding to another page on a mouseover why not (if it's not clear to the user) advise that clicking will take them somewhere else. That's just nicer.

Your markup:

```
<div class="unique">
   <div>
     <p>Lines of text</p>
     <p>Extra lines of text</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var fetchContent = $('.unique').html();
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.unique').on('mouseenter',function(){
        $(this).html('Click here and we\'ll go somewhere else!');
        });

    $('.unique').on('mouseleave',function(){
        $(this).html(fetchContent);
        });

    $('.unique').on('click',function(){
        location.href='go-to-your-url';
        });
    });
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6b8ku/1/

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
<script>
$( ".unique" ).click(function() {
  window.location = LINK_TO_A_SPECIFIC_URL;
});
</script>
```

You can change the mouse icon, when mouse over the div :

```
<script>
$( ".unique" ).mouseover(function() {
  $(this).css( 'cursor', 'pointer' );
});
</script>
```

here is the JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/9zyeX/

Comment: yes that would be ok, but the link where do i put it? i want people to be able to click on it not just show them the pointer.

Comment: @RaduS first JS code is about link and second one is about mouse icon

Comment: @pmp because they rely on anchor tags to find the links

Answer (score 1):

Try this, should wrap the whole lot in an anchor.

I'm not sure if its semantic but should work

```
$('.unique').after(
  '<a href="http://www.google.com">'+$('.unique').html()+'</a>'
).remove();
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z98cS/)**